# when I open code blocks and start to write my code, a blank space occurs on my screen

Tags: c, macos, codeblocks

So this blank space remain until I quit code blocks. It even shows if I use any other app while using code blocks in background. It keep quitting unexpectedly while writing my codes. I'm using 17.12 version on Mac, How can I fix it?

[image]
[image]

Here is my code:

```c
int main() {
    int age = 0;
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly some kind of dialog that gets "sticky"? Is there any contents at that place before it goes gray? If you minimize all windows, including the IDE, does it still stay? There's no dialog or other window behind all other windows? There's no indication that there might be more than one window open from Code::Blocks?

Comment: ...On Windows F5 refreshes (or re-writes) all visible windows.  I think it is Command R on Mac OS.  Does that clear the shadow ?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No there is no content before it goes gray. 
yes even it is still gray even if I minimize the window , it only moves from one place to another when I want to write something. 
only one window is open from codeblocks

Answer (score 0):

In `scanf` you have to provide a pointer to where you want the result stored, e.g. `&age`:

```c
int main() {
    int age;
    printf("Enter age: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("Age is %d \n", age);
    return 0;
}
```

---

For what it is worth, if you wrote this in Xcode, you will see a warning:

[image]

I am surprised that when you built your project that you did not see a similar warning in the “Build log” (maybe it was there, but just buried amidst a bunch of other log messages), but I am not familiar with your IDE, so I cannot say.

Comment: I know about this,
I don't have problem with code. I know how to write is correctly.
my problem is if I even write an alphabet this code blocks quit unexpectedly and before it, it shows this grey blank space. I haves used it the same way that time I didn't had any problem but now this problem has occurred.